# Reading JSON from FileStream

Tags: c#, json, filestream

In Xamarin.Forms project I have JSON file saved as Embedded Resource. I get it as FileStream by calling:

```
var assembly = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;

FileStream fileStream = assembly.GetFiles()[0];
```

How do I parse this stream to json string?
I know it is most likely super dumb question but I am confused, all I achieved was some random characters.

Comment: 1. Read the entire stream into a string. 2. Deserialize string into json using library of your choice.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0#how-to-read-json-as-net-objects-deserialize where Microsoft describes how to deserialize JSON. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3314213/7565574 how to read embedded resources. I think GetFiles() would return the assembly itself.

Comment: If you have a `Stream` and you want to get the text the stream represents, create a `StreamReader` using the stream and read the text using the `StreamReader` (e.g. `ReadToEnd()`, `ReadLine()`, etc.). See duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get the raw string from the JSON file by using

`string jsonText = File.ReadAllText("/path/to/file.txt")`

From there, you can convert the JSON string into an object (if needed):

`MyClass jsonObj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyClass>(jsonText);`

Don't forget to import `System.Text.Json.Serialization`, `System.Text.Json`, and `System.IO` when working with JSON files.

You're having errors because you're trying to get a literal `FileStream`, which is not the intended use for it. You can read more about serializing JSONs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0

Comment: What is JsonUtility? Is it from Unity? For new .NET code System.Text.Json is recommended by MS.

Comment: Sorry you're right, JsonUtility is from Unity, fixing it now

Comment: So basically I did the same thing that @JeffChen posted. What I discovered is the problem is  loading the file, not my reading it. Thanks for help